# PHP - Can't submit form to handler

Tags: php, forms

Here is my Code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" action="../../../wamp/www/abc.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="text1" id="username" />
            <input type="submit"  />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The abc.php file is located in `C:/wamp/www/abc.php`

```
<html>
   <body>
       Hello World
       <?php
            echo "Hello";
            echo $_GET["username"];
       ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

In the form, when I press the Submit button, only "Hello World" is displayed.

The value entered in the textbox is not displayed at all. Even the "Hello" message printed inside the php code is not displayed.

How can i display the Value ?

Comment: Please have a look into the browser "source code". It should not contain any php, since PHP is done server-side, and only the resulting HTML is sent to the browser. If `<?php` is sent to the browser, PHP execution is not invoked by the server, possibly due to a misconfiguration.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I do see the php code in red font. I am using Mozilla Firefox. By the way, Google Chrome also gives the same output. Any suggestions to fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

text1 is the name of your input, so the correct PHP code would be.

```
<?php 
     echo "Hello ";
     echo $_GET['text1'];
?>
```

Comment: Tried it, but it still prints "Hello World"

Comment: Do you have a "?text1=World" in your URL? If so, delete that part of the url and try again.

Comment: Still getting the same output.

Comment: the form url is: file:///C:/Users/Devang/Desktop/def.html                                                           after i press the submit button, it changes to: file:///C:/wamp/www/abc.php?username=abcdefg

Comment: Ok, you are not running PHP in a server... try to install WAMP or XAMP to run your PHP scripts.

Comment: I am running the script in WAMP on my PC.

Comment: Your URL says that you are trying to run the php file directly. You should be running it from a URL similar to http://localhost/abc.php

Comment: Got it!! I tried running the script as localhost and the correct output was displayed. Thanks mate !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, get array is created using name attr not id one.

```
 echo $_GET["text1"];
```

Comment: Tried it, but it still prints "Hello World"

Comment: If you have only "Hello world" it means that the echo "Hello" is not executed. I would test the PHP instalation before.

Answer (score 0):

There is two solution for you should use :

**First Way :Change your php code:**

```
<?php
  echo "hello";
  echo $_GET["text1"];
?>
```

**Second Way: Chnage your HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If second "Hello" from echo is not displayed, there is a problem with your PHP installation.

Comment: PHP is installed correctly. I am using latest edition of WAMP. Till now, I have been able to run all the basic programs utilising loops, classes, functions, etc. without any issue.

Comment: Still, there is a problem with your PHP installation now. If echo "Hello" is not displayed, it means PHP is not working.